# Counterexamples on Borel measurable function.

Tags: measure-theory, examples-counterexamples

I studied two important theorems on Borel measurable functions which are as follows:

$1.$ Every continuous function defined on a Borel set is Borel measurable.

$2.$ Monotone function defined on a Borel set is Borel measurable.

I want to understand why the assumption that the domain $X$ is Borel set important.For that I want to find counterexamples to the following statements:

$1.$ Let $X\subset \mathbb R$.Every continuous function $f:X\to \mathbb R$ is Borel measurable.

$2.$ Let $X\subset \mathbb R$.Every monotone function on $X$ is Borel measurable.

I think that to find counterexamples to this problem,I must find a non-Borel set.Can someone help me find the counterexamples because counterexamples always help to build intuition.

Comment: When you say in 1. "continuous function" do you mean the restriction to $X$ of an ordinary continuous function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ ? Or does $X$ have some topology w.r.t. which $f$ is continuous ?

Comment: @KurtG. I mean $f$ is continuous on $X$ w.r.t the subspace topology on $X$.

Comment: If ${\mathscr B}(X)$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X$'s own topology (subspace or not) then the continuous $f$ is trivially Borel measurable.